# Angular 2 avoid compiling images defined in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a `styles.css` in my Angular 2 application.
It's referred to in `app.styles` object in `.angular-cli.json`.
Inside that css I have urls to background images, e.g:

```
.bg-game {
  background-image: url("assets/app/game_bg_768.jpg");
}
```

When compiling the app, it seems Angular 2 copies the files from their location into the root folder of the compiled app and adds to its name a random hash.

For instance `assets/app/game_bg_768.jpg` will be copied to dist/ (compiled app folder) as `game_bg_768.023f195663c85e8f0322.jpg`.

Then in the styles css compiled by Angular 2, the reference will be changed accordingly:

```
.bg-game {
  background-image: url("game_bg_768.023f195663c85e8f0322.jpg");
}
```

I'd like to disable that whole process, only for images that are linked to in CSS, I don't want to disable random hashes generation for the whole app.

The reason behind this - I'm preloading `assets/app/game_bg_768.jpg` before the game starts, but since a different url is specified in the compiled css, during the game another request is made to load `game_bg_768.023f195663c85e8f0322.jpg`.

Another reason is, I'd like my images to remain in my assets folder, I don't want them to be duplicated into the root folder of the compiled app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute URLs to avoid it.

```
.bg-game {
  background-image: url("/assets/app/game_bg_768.jpg");
}
```

However, after you do that, the compiler won't check if the images exist in assets directory anymore.

Also, if you are deploying your app to a subdirectory of the domain, the browser will look for the asset on `/assets` instead of `/subdirectory/assets`. Using `base-href` or `deploy-url` won't help.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea, you need to reconfigure webpack settings and [set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248355/2313116) corresponding `loader` settings.
**BUT**, AFAIK by default AngularCLI doesn't provide a visible config file for webpack, so, you need to make some [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42406194/2313116) for that and keep in mind aftermath or you can try to play with [assets configuration](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration) in `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: Is there perhaps a simpler workaround such as defining the background-image css inside the HTML instead of instead the CSS? Perhaps that way Angular 2 won't get to it?

Comment: @RoyiBernthal you are right, it will be more easy to do)

Comment: @RoyiBernthal you can edit plain html or move it to component/directive with a template, both variants should be ok. 
Just FYI: There is no influence of Angular 2. This renaming stuff produced by webpack which is embedded build system in Angular CLI. You can use different build system and keep using Angular CLI, but it's advanced scenario, more details: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-moving-out-of-the-cli